# Find consecutively larger Values in column

Tags: python, pandas

Say i have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,4,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9],'B':[1,2,2,2,2,5,9,8,8,10,11,10]})
print df

    A   B
0   5   1
1   4   2
2   7   2
3   8   2
4   1   2
5   2   5
6   3   9
7   4   8
8   5   8
9   7  10
10  8  11
11  9  10
```

And I want to find only the consecutively higher values in df.A, therefore df would become:

```
    A   B
0   5   1
2   7   2
3   8   2
11  9  10
```

What is the best(read fastest) way forward here; I have tried something quite complicated but alas, it's actually slower than looping thorough the whole frame.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining *consecutively higher values*?

Comment: @Psidom each new value in `df.A` should be higher than the last occurrence of the last largest value in `df.A`, and so on and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works only if B grows monotonously:

```
df.cummax().drop_duplicates('A')
#    A   B 
#0   5   1 
#2   7   2 
#3   8   2 
#11  9  10
```

This one is more general:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].cummax()
df.drop_duplicates('C')[['A','B']]
```

Comment: Brilliant sir, beautifully simple though it is, shamefully it passed me by. It just turned a 5 min loop into a 5 second loop. Wonderful.